# Multiple rows returned with unique key?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given those 3 simple SQLAlchemy models:

```
class Customer(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uid = sa.Column(sa.Unicode, nullable=False, unique=True)


class Handset(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'handsets'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    imei = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(15), nullable=False, unique=True)


class Channel(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'channels'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)

    customer_id = sa.Column(sa.ForeignKey(Customer.id), nullable=False)
    handset_id = sa.Column(sa.ForeignKey(Handset.id), nullable=False)

    customer = relationship(Customer, backref='channels', lazy='joined')
    handset = relationship(Handset, backref='channels', lazy='joined')


    __table_args__ = (
        sa.Index('uk_channels_customer_handset',
                 customer_id, handset_id,
                 unique=True),
    )
```

I don't understand why this query:

```
session.query(Channel).filter(Handset.imei == '1234', Customer.uid == 'test').one_or_none()
```

Throws `multiple rows found` execption, when there are multiple `Channel`s associated with the `handset_id`, but with distinct `customer_id` while this query, works OK:

```
c = aliased(Customer)
h = aliased(Handset)
session.query(Channel).enable_eagerloads(False).join(c).join(h).filter(
    c.uid == 'test', h.imei == '1234',
).one_or_none()
```

How can I load channel with eager loading of customer & handset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1st query produces an implicit cross join between handsets, customers and channels (which is the source of multiple rows for one) + 2 left joins (from customers and handsets for eager load), which is probably not what you want:

```
In [7]: print(session.query(Channel).filter(Handset.imei == '1234', Customer.uid == 'test'))
SELECT channels.id AS channels_id, channels.customer_id AS channels_customer_id, channels.handset_id AS channels_handset_id, customers_1.id AS customers_1_id, customers_1.uid AS customers_1_uid, handsets_1.id AS handsets_1_id, handsets_1.imei AS handsets_1_imei 
FROM handsets, customers, channels LEFT OUTER JOIN customers AS customers_1 ON customers_1.id = channels.customer_id LEFT OUTER JOIN handsets AS handsets_1 ON handsets_1.id = channels.handset_id 
WHERE handsets.imei = ? AND customers.uid = ?
```

The second works as you explicitly define the joins and disable eager load left joins. The 1st query would work using [`has()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.has):

```
In [17]: print(session.query(Channel).filter(Channel.handset.has(imei='1234'), 
                                             Channel.customer.has(uid='test')))
SELECT channels.id AS channels_id, channels.customer_id AS channels_customer_id, channels.handset_id AS channels_handset_id, customers_1.id AS customers_1_id, customers_1.uid AS customers_1_uid, handsets_1.id AS handsets_1_id, handsets_1.imei AS handsets_1_imei 
FROM channels LEFT OUTER JOIN customers AS customers_1 ON customers_1.id = channels.customer_id LEFT OUTER JOIN handsets AS handsets_1 ON handsets_1.id = channels.handset_id 
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM handsets 
WHERE handsets.id = channels.handset_id AND handsets.imei = ?)) AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM customers 
WHERE customers.id = channels.customer_id AND customers.uid = ?))
```

In essence this separately checks that there exists both handset and customer for this channel with the given predicates and then left joins the customer and handset to this channel.

You could also instruct SQLAlchemy that you're using [an explicit join in the second query and to eager load using that](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#explicit-join-eagerload) with [`contains_eager()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager):

```
In [28]: print(session.query(Channel).\
    join(c).join(h).\
    options(contains_eager(Channel.handset, alias=h),
            contains_eager(Channel.customer, alias=c)).\
    filter(
        c.uid == 'test', h.imei == '1234',
    ))
SELECT customers_1.id AS customers_1_id, customers_1.uid AS customers_1_uid, handsets_1.id AS handsets_1_id, handsets_1.imei AS handsets_1_imei, channels.id AS channels_id, channels.customer_id AS channels_customer_id, channels.handset_id AS channels_handset_id 
FROM channels JOIN customers AS customers_1 ON customers_1.id = channels.customer_id JOIN handsets AS handsets_1 ON handsets_1.id = channels.handset_id 
WHERE customers_1.uid = ? AND handsets_1.imei = ?
```

which is in my opinion the cleaner solution.